# transferring data between the data generator and a web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-appservice

I have a data generator, that generates some data. It uses the internal model that looks like this.

```
class InMemoryDataFrame:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.dict: Dict[Any, Tuple] = {}
```

It is a basic dictionary (but idea in the future is to rewrite to something more effective like a real dataframe or something).

This data - for now - is generated within `azure app service` and thus it is enough for me to have this Python object and use it everywhere withing the application. I convert this object to the corresponding output type (for example `pyarrow` table) and then perform necessary transformations (partitioning, conversion to `csv` or `parquet`). After that I zip it into the archive and store into the `azure storage account`.

However the idea is to separate the generator from the main application to prevent generator from clogging the app service (as data generation can take some time). The idea is basically to turn app service into an `azure function` (or a set of them or a separate `app service`), while the generator will have its own `app service` instance too.

What data type should I use (or would be better to use) to transfer the data between the generator and the web service? I don't want to perform transformations in the generator, as I want to limit its functionality only to the data generation. The amount of data can be like 1m+ records.

Is plain JSON enough? Or should I use some binary protocols like protobuf or avro?

Comment: Azure Web app and other Azure resources interact with Azure Resource manager which is nothing but a rest api request which is in JSON format, Refer here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-environments/create-or-update?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01&tabs=HTTP So Json format would work. But if your task is data specific then using protobuf or avro would help you to work with data analysis tool in azure like ADF, Azure synapse pipelines. But these data pipelines can also be triggered via rest api and json transformation can also be done.

Comment: Oh, I see. Right now we do have an ADF pipeline - it basically calls the App Service and retrieve that archived zip with data when it is generated. I just not sure if transferring generate data itself using JSON - before converting it to the output time - is better than using the binary protocol. We also wanted to allow users - potentially - to download parts of the generated data when it is still being generated.

Comment: Json will always work with all the services and real time streaming services too in future like event grid, Kafka, service bus messaging. Avro will be more beneficial for data analysis tasks.

Comment: Interesting. I have always though that protobufs are better for stuff like that. Though I never understood really why people use binary protocols in the first place.  What use cases make them essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I conclude that:-

If you want to make use of Data generator in Azure Web App's backend and want to interact with Azure resources, Make use of JSON as your data type, As Azure Web App and other Azure resources interact with Azure Resource Manager which is nothing but a Rest API.
[App Service Environments - Create Or Update - REST API (Azure App Service) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-environments/create-or-update?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01&tabs=HTTP)

> Though I never understood really why people use binary protocols in  the first place. What use cases make them essential.

- Binary protocols make the data compact, Thus it enables faster data transmission and reduced storage space.
- Binary protocols have faster encoding and decoding capabilities as compared to text based formats which results in faster processing of large scale data.
- Binary protocols, Avro, Protobuf has a specific schema, This makes the data or the code easy to troubleshoot at any point due to pre-defined schema. Also, It is supported by almost every modern programming language.
- Binary protocols work better with real time data that is sent by Sensors, and IOT Devices.
  Refer this [MS Q&A answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/155001/sendig-avro-structure-message-to-azure-iot-hub) by AshokPeddakotla-MSFT which states, IOTHUB Supports sending data in Avro format.
  Refer this [MS Q & A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/251186/sending-and-receiving-avro-formatted-events-to-eve) which states, Sending of AVRO based data in azure Event Hub.

If your 1mn+ data requires a  predefined schema and faster encoding, decoding, serialization and de-serialization with faster execution, You can make use of AVRO or other binary protocols. I will recommend JSON data type if you want to communicate with Azure Resources internally via Azure resource manager. But If you are planning to just send the data via generator and then store it in Azure Storage, You can send AVRO based data to Azure storage account call it inside Azure Functions or ADF pipeline or even Machine Learning Design.

You can store your events in Azure storage [**Queue Trigger**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python-v2,isolated-process,nodejs-v4,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) and then call it inside an Azure Function:-

[image]

You can also create Azure Functions Http Trigger to receive your queue messages and call it inside your ADF pipeline like below:-

My Function code:-

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Retrieve the message from the queue
    connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconstrg78;AccountKey=xxxxxxx+AStCnBmfg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
    queue_name = 'myqueue'

    queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, queue_name=queue_name)
    
    messages = queue_client.receive_messages()

    for message in messages:
        message_content = message.content
        queue_client.delete_message(message)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Message from the queue: {message_content}", status_code=200)

    return func.HttpResponse("No messages in the queue", status_code=404)
```

Deploy it in your Function app and then call it in ADF:-

[image]

You can generate the data in JSON Format in the Web App then transform it into AVRO, Protobuf or other Binary protocols and utilize it in ADF for Data transformation or send it as an event in the Azure Event Hub.

Also, As you are storing your data into Azure storage account, It makes your job easier to connect Azure Storage to any Data pipeline via ADF, Synapse or even Event Hub or IOTHub.

You can directly add your Data generator in Azure Functions > And then add it as an Event in your Web app like below:-

> Note- Only EventGrid Trigger is supported here:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for overview!

In my case the json might contain several hundreds and keys and each of them can have several millions items (integers, strings or even composite values). I am also able to split this dictionary into smaller chunks of independent columns and send them independently. But I guess as I am using web services it would be better to go with plain JSON due to usage of Azure Resource Manager. I can use binary protocol if I store this data to the storage account first and process later I guess.